# Topological space, Baire space

Tags: general-topology, analysis

How the open upper half plane with the rationals on the x-axis is a baire space ?? The hint given is : " since the set contains a open dense baire space i.e. R*(0, infinity) it is baire". But I am not being able to prove it manually. Please give me some hint.

Comment: I got the answer of this question. Can anybody tell me why this is not a G-delta subset of R2?

Comment: You can edit the question...

Comment: Sorry but I couldn't get how you are telling that if X is G-delta in R2 then Q will be G-delta in R ? What is the homomorphism ??

Comment: The $x$-axis is also a $G_\delta$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$. And $Q$ in the $x$-axis is isometric trivially to $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2):

Fact: if $X$ contains a dense subspace $D$ that is Baire in the subspace topology, then $X$ is itself also Baire.

Proof : let $U_n$ be a sequence of dense and open subsets of $X$; you have to show its intersection is dense in $X$. So $U_n \cap D$ is such a sequence in $D$ so $\bigcap_n (U_n \cap D)$ is dense in $D$ by assumption that $D$ is Baire and a dense subset of a dense subset is dense and this has $\bigcap U_n$ as a superset, so the latter set is also dense.

The upper open half plane, being homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$ is such a subspace in your space $X$.

The rationals on the $x$-axis, call it $Q$, are closed and hence a $G_\delta$ in $X$.

That example shows that in general closed or $G_\delta$ subsets of a Baire space are not necessarily Baire. If $X$ were a $G_\delta$ in the plane, show that $\mathbb{Q}$ would be a $G_\delta$ in $\mathbb{R}$, and that is certainly not the case..